# Can a webserver like Tomcat be used only as a TCP server?

Tags: tomcat, ssl, tcp, webserver

I have to handle 1000 ( worst case ) clients at a time. And all the connections will be in connected state forever. Client doesn't send data in `HTTP/HTTPS` protocol rather raw streams of bytes are sent from both sides. I was thinking to use a webserver like `Tomcat`, `lighthttpd` etc. but they handle only http protocols. I also need `SSL` over `TCP`.

Is it possible that I can configure a webserver that only handle raw `TCP` and `SSL` ?

Comment: Your server should reflect the content you are serving, e.g. http server for many types of content, ftp server for file transfers, etc. So what is the content you will be serving?

Comment: I don't have any standard application level protocol like ( http, ftp etc. ). I have customized packet structure that will be sent as a stream of bytes.

Comment: @JamesKPolk for TCP, http or ftp packet is a bytes stream, TCP doesn't care about what is content and how the content is structured.

Comment: Well, then I don't see how there is any chance that tomcat or any existing server can implement your custom protocol.

Comment: @JamesKPolk that I want to know, if it is possible to use as a TCP server. To be frank, I am thinking to use off-the-shelf solution to manage all the connections things. I don't want to implement all non blocking sockets and multithreading and everything.

Comment: Apache with modules can implement other protocols than HTTP(S) (like Whois or EPP for example) but that seems far overkill for what you are doing. In your programming language there are certainly libraries/frameworks to implement simple TCP servers or TLS (not SSL) servers.

Comment: "all the connections will be in connected state forever" that is an assumption that you can not count on as you do not control all the paths... any element in the network, like a firewall or a NAT layer could cut the connection at the TCP level (either sending a FIN or just stopping to forward packets) after some given time. You have to program your client and server to handle that gracefully (starting with having keepalives for example)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek sure, it is possible to develop a TLS/TCP server in any modern language. But the question is, how much effort and time is needed to make it robust with availability of 24/7 and 365.4 days for around 1000 concurrent connections. The idea was to let any webserver handle connection things and concentrate on other logic.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek `keep-alive` should also be possible to set in any webserver.

Comment: If you want to use a webserver... just define a way to use HTTP for your own protocol messages and then problem (mostly) solved you can use all HTTP existing software. However 1000  concurrent connections is not a big number, and I still think you could find frameworks in your language. For example you have "twisted" in Python, an asynchronous framework to build TCP/TLS servers. And many other options I am sure in multiple languages.

Comment: Also have a look at websockets (over HTTP(S)) if you insist on using a webserver. After an initial HTTP negotiation it then becomes a pure binary bidirectional protocol.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Do you have an example for a framework for C\C++ ?